# kafka-streams-scala version vis-à-vis kafka-streams version

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams

Should the version of org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams-scala that I use in a project, be identical to the  org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams version?

Or can I, for example, use kafka-streams-scala version 2.2.0 with kafka-streams-scala version 2.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same. There is no guarantee that it works correctly if you mix different versions.